# Create and use in same execution cycle

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see the DDL below:

```
create database db1
use db1
--More DDL to create tables etc
```

The error I get is: `Database 'DB1' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.`

Does the create statement have to be in a separate execution cycle to the create database statement?

I have spent time googling this, but I have not found my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the execution cycle you're looking for by using the default batch terminator GO between commands:

```
create database db1
go
use db1
```